# Is there a rule or setting when Narrator ignore aria-label on element while aria-label's value same as element 's content?

Tags: html, accessibility, element

When I set aria-label's value same as button's content, the screen-reader cannot readout aria-label.

`<button aria-label="Close"><span>Close</span></button>`

But when I change aria-label's value different from button's content, the screen-reader readout the aria-label.

`<button aria-label="Close X"><span>Close</span></button>`

Is there a rule or setting when Narrator ignore aria-label on element while aria-label's value same as element 's content?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not any convention about this.

> By default, an HTML element will use its text content as the
> accessibility label. If an element has `aria-label`, the accessible name
> becomes the string that it's passed in the attribute.

Your code works with the chrome screen reader extension.
please take a look at [this](https://www.aditus.io/aria/aria-label/) link for more information.

There is also a chrome extension that helps you with missing ARIA labels, misused ARIA roles, and an incomplete keyboard called `ARIA DevTools`. here is the [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aria-devtools/dneemiigcbbgbdjlcdjjnianlikimpck?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about the **[accessible name](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#dfn-accessible-name)**.  An element can only have **one** accessible name and it's announced by the screen reader when you navigate to that element, along with it's [role](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#dfn-role) and value or [state](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#dfn-state), as per [WCAG 4.1.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#name-role-value).  (It can also have an *[accessible description](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#dfn-accessible-description)*.)

The accessible name is calculated using a precedence order defined in "[Accessible Name and Description Computation 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2)".  It's essentially a big "if then else" statement and when one of the conditions are true, the rest are ignored.  The order of precedence (which is a little oversimplified here but you can see the details in the aforementioned link), is:

1. aria-labelledby
2. aria-label
3. `<label>` element
4. from content
5. from tooltip

In your example, you have *two* sources of the accessible name, #2 and #4.  The `aria-label` (#2, "Close X") will be found first so the content (#4, "Close") will be ignored.